# Possible to build Relation Type between two specific Content Types?

Tags: entities

I have created Content Types: Person, Story, Company, Series, Article, Basic Page, plus other content types in the Node bundle.

I want the Relation Type between Person and Story only (i.e. "is author of", "authored by") but all online instructions I read say that the Relation Type should be between bundles. However, that scope is too wide.

The display page shows
Entity Collector
Relation Type "is author of"
Select an entity "" (is null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a question of interpretation of what I could see. What I couldn't see was that the Relation Type had been created, and I did not know how the "relations" were populated. Watching Johann Falk's screencast another time showed me how to do this.